# My over redirected window doesn't work normally if I open it from another window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python code, which opens an over redirected window, but some things doesn't working normally. If I open it from another window, my dragging function will doesn't work normally, and if I interact with this window, the window's title and icon will appear on the taskbar. I don't know where is the problem, because I hadn't changed the code. (I only putted it to a simple function.).

Here is the code:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def cmd():
    
    lastClickX = 0
    lastClickY = 0

    def SaveLastClickPos(event):
        global lastClickX, lastClickY
        lastClickX = event.x
        lastClickY = event.y

    def Dragging(event):
        deltax = event.x - lastClickX
        deltay = event.y - lastClickY
        x = window.winfo_x() + deltax
        y = window.winfo_y() + deltay

        window.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))

    def leave(event):
        CloseButton["image"] = CloseButtonImg

    def enter(event):
        CloseButton["image"] = CloseButtonImg3

    def close():
        for i in range(5):
            time.sleep(0.01)
            window.geometry("%sx%s" % (window.winfo_height() - 2, window.winfo_width() - 2))
            window.geometry("+%s+%s" % (window.winfo_x() + 1, window.winfo_y() + 1))

            window.attributes("-alpha", 0.6)
            window.update()

        window.destroy()


    def opening():
        window.geometry("390x390")
        window.update()

        time.sleep(0.01)
        window.geometry("%sx%s" % (window.winfo_height() + 2, window.winfo_width() + 2))
        window.geometry("+%s+%s" % (window.winfo_x() - 1, window.winfo_y() - 1))

        window.attributes("-alpha", 0.6)
        window.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        window.geometry("%sx%s" % (window.winfo_height() + 2, window.winfo_width() + 2))
        window.geometry("+%s+%s" % (window.winfo_x() - 1, window.winfo_y() - 1))

        window.attributes("-alpha", 0.7)
        window.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        window.geometry("%sx%s" % (window.winfo_height() + 2, window.winfo_width() + 2))
        window.geometry("+%s+%s" % (window.winfo_x() - 1, window.winfo_y() - 1))

        window.attributes("-alpha", 0.8)
        window.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        window.geometry("%sx%s" % (window.winfo_height() + 2, window.winfo_width() + 2))
        window.geometry("+%s+%s" % (window.winfo_x() - 1, window.winfo_y() - 1))

        window.attributes("-alpha", 0.9)
        window.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        window.geometry("%sx%s" % (window.winfo_height() + 2, window.winfo_width() + 2))
        window.geometry("+%s+%s" % (window.winfo_x() - 1, window.winfo_y() - 1))

        window.attributes("-alpha", 1)
        window.update()



    window = Toplevel()
    window.overrideredirect(True)

    Fram = Frame(window, height=30, width=400, bg="white")
    Fram.place(y=0, x=0)
    Label(Fram, text="Window", font="Arial 10", bg="white", fg="black").place(y=2, x=2)
    window.attributes('-topmost', True)
    window.geometry("400x400+500+300")
    window.bind('<Button-1>', SaveLastClickPos)
    CloseButtonImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Images\\Close1.png"))

    CloseButtonImg3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Images\\Close3.png"))
    CloseButton = Button(window, image=CloseButtonImg, bg="white", borderwidth=0, activebackground="white",
                         relief=SUNKEN, command=close)
    CloseButton.place(y=-2, x=370)
    CloseButton.bind("<Enter>", enter)
    CloseButton.bind("<Leave>", leave)
    Fram.bind('<B1-Motion>', Dragging)

    window.after(1, func=opening)
    window.mainloop()


k = Tk()
Button(k, text="Haha", command=cmd).pack()
k.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works in my Windows 10 running Python 3.10.1.